# Is possible to link an online font file to PIL ImageFont.truetype()?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

Instead of downloading the font locally and link it to ImageFont.truetyp()  to be like this:

```
from pillow import ImageFont
font = ImageFont.truetype('Roboto-Regular.ttf', size=10)
```

Can I do something like this:

```
from pillow import ImageFont
font = ImageFont.truetype('https://github.com/googlefonts/roboto/blob/master/src/hinted/Roboto-Regular.ttf', size=10)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[**`ImageFont.true_type`**](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/ImageFont.html#PIL.ImageFont.truetype) takes a file-like object.

Python's standard library, [**`urllib.request.urlopen`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.urlopen) returns a file-like object.

The following should work:

```
from pillow import ImageFont
from urllib.request import urlopen

truetype_url = 'https://github.com/googlefonts/roboto/blob/master/src/hinted/Roboto-Regular.ttf?raw=true'
font = ImageFont.truetype(urlopen(truetype_url), size=10)
```

edit: As @flyer2403 [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72687803/1084416), to make that particular url work you need to add `?raw=true` to the end.

Comment: Cool, that looks even simpler!

Comment: Wonderful solution.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I liked [your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61519480/1084416) because it was a full solution, with a screenshot! I only really posted so there wasn't a dependency on [**`requests`**](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/), (not that it's a bad thing, but if there's a solution in vanilla I like to provide it)

Comment: @PeterWood That's fine by me - I am always happy to learn. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I also like to learn. That's partly why I answer questions. I look up the documentation, try things out, and post alternatives if I think they're useful. I previously didn't know much about `pillow` or Python 3's `urllib` library, but I want to learn, so took the opportunity.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to download the contents of the font with `requests` and then make a file-like object out of them with `BytesIO` to pass to `ImageFont.truetype()` in place of the filename:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from PIL import Image, ImageFont, ImageDraw
import requests
import io

# Load font from URI
r = requests.get('https://github.com/ProgrammingFonts/ProgrammingFonts/raw/master/Droid-Sans-Mono/droid-sans-mono-1.00/Droid%20Sans%20Mono.ttf', allow_redirects=True)
font = ImageFont.truetype(io.BytesIO(r.content), size=24)

# Create a black canvas and get drawing context
canvas = Image.new('RGB', (400,200))
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(canvas)

# Write in our font
draw.text((10, 10), "Hello, nice to meet you.", font=font, fill=(255,255,255))

canvas.save('result.png')
```

[image]

I can't work out the correct URL for your font, so I used a random, different one.

Comment: As `ImageFont.true_type` now takes a file-like object, could you pass the result of [**`urllib.request.urlopen`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.urlopen)?

Comment: oh nice, thanks alot. A very interesting way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Just needed to make a slight change to @PeterWood's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61519785/7098535) to make this work on google colab:

```
truetype_url = 'https://github.com/googlefonts/roboto/blob/master/src/hinted/Roboto-Regular.ttf?raw=true'
```

I needed to add `?raw=true` to the end of the truetype_url